# WordPress set clean url with query args and get values

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress I have set a query arg in ajax like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_prepare_link', 'prepare_link');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_prepare_link', 'prepare_link');

function prepare_link() {
    //Do some logic and get the models name
    $url = add_query_arg( array(
            'models' => aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc,
        ), 'http://example.com/cars/compare/' );
    echo $url;
    wp_die();
}
```

So after this I have got my url like this

`http://example.com/cars/compare/?models=aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc`

So from jQuery I am doing redirect the page to the response url like this

```
jQuery('a.compare-vechicles').click(function(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: script.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action : 'get_prepare_link',
        },
        success: function(data){
            window.location = data; //Redirect to the prepared link
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to make it as seo friendly url. So the output url should be shown like this

```
http://example.com/cars/compare/models/aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc
```

So to achieve this I have made like this

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^compare/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
        'top');
}
```

But its not working at all. So can someone tell me how can I achieve this? Also how can access the model values? Any help or suggestions would be really appreciable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add few modification to your rewrite function:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^compare/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?page=compare&models=$matches[1]',
        'top');
```

We tell WordPress that we want to use those GET parameters by adding a query_vars filter

```
add_filter('query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'page'; 
    $vars[] = 'models'; 
    return $vars;
});
```

Then to get value of GET param "user" use:

```
get_query_var( 'models' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am using add_query_arg in ajax function to prepare the url and from js I am doing redirect the url as per the response . So in that case how can I use 

`add_filter('query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'page'; 
    $vars[] = 'models'; 
    return $vars;
});
`

Comment: Try to write the same in ajax call

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you. Can you please edit your code so that I can understand it?